# Ul opções contato facebook

Tags: jquery, css3

No `facebook`, quando vamos na opção de ver a lista de contatos que enviamos pedidos, temos lá um botão escrito "Solicitação de amizade enviada". Ao clicar nesse botão, vem algumas opções em lista as quais podemos escolher.

Essas opções são `ul's`. Mas o que eu preciso é de fazer uma **popup** com uma caraterística daquelas. Se notarem, observarão que, caso o **botão** esteja no final da página, não havendo assim como a lista (`popup`) abrir para baixo, a lista abre para cima.

Como conseguir efeito em uma `ul`?

Notem que na imagem abaixo, a **popup** abre abaixo do botão
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Enquanto nessa outra figura, a **popup** abre acima do **botão** porque o botão está no final da pagina então tecnicamente, se a **popup** abrisse para baixo, as opções não apareceriam.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entendi parcialmente o que você quer fazer Carlos. Acho que é melhor se você puder esclarecer e/ou talvez colocar alguns exemplos visuais pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: Ok, adicionado ilustração.

Comment: Não, não resolve. Fazer a **popup** não é o problema. Minha dificuldade é como posicioná-la cima do botão caso ao abri-la para baixo não der para ver toda a **popup** por causa do fim da pagina igual o que ocorre com o **select option**